# 08-28 NoClassDefFoundError NotificationBuilder

Tags: android, dialog, android-widget

I was creating notification using builder class and using android 4.1 version (API level 16).
But the application is generating exception as 
`08-28 12:39:00.321: E/AndroidRuntime(2311): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.Notification$Builder`
Necessary packages are already imported.

```
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this);
notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
notification.setTicker("My Notification");
notification.setContentInfo("New event");
mgr.notify(123, notification.build());
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you run it on device? emulator? which version of android was where?

Comment: I am running it on emulator with API level 10 Checking on emulator with API level 16 now.

Comment: Yeah it worked on emulator with API level 16 thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run you application on a device / emulator with API level >= 11 in order to use the [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) class.